# The discrimination between short and long option is only `-`?

Tags: command-line, options

On `Unix` system, options begin with `-` is short option, while options begin with `--` is long option. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Generally but not always.  For instance `find` options have no single-letter abbreviations, but only have one leading hyphen.  `find . -name '*.txt'`

Comment: yeah typically. the trick for long options is to make `-` an option letter. there's an answer here somewhere - *(i thought it was one of @glennjackman's but cant find it now)* about it. but: `while getopts :-:others valid_name -params --long_is_in_OPTARG; do :; done`

Comment: @Wildcard - those arent really options. The only options find takes are about symlinks in the main. Those are the script primitives and they follow all of the operands. find is weird, though.

Comment: Related: [Why does my ls --help not work?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224451)

Comment: @Wildcard, those are not options but _predicates_ / _operators_. `find` does accept single letter options (`-H`, `-L`...), the GNU implementations long options (`--help`, `--version`). Like for many other command, you can end those options with `--`, after which you can pass regular arguments (file paths and predicates some of which start with `-` (`-a`, `-print`...) some of which don't (`!`, `(`...)).

Comment: I stand corrected.  The most helpful single sentence I've read about `find` is: *["`find`'s business is evaluating expressions -- not locating files. Yes, `find` certainly locates files; but that's really just a side effect."](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch09_12.htm)*  So of course, makes sense that those are *operands* (or predicates, or operators), not options.

Comment: These find operands are called `primaries` in the documentation.  They still can be seen that there is a preference for single dash long options in `UNIX` - maybe because Multics uses single dash long options as well.

Answer (score 7):

That is part of the GNU coding standards, so all GNU (and many non-GNU) software follows it. However, it's by no means an absolute standard; there are other ways of implementing this, such as:

- `-Wlong-option`: originated from the C compiler, and specified as such in POSIX.
- `-long-option` (i.e., single-dash): supported by most applications (usually as an alternative to the double-dash version) that don't have any short options.
- `+long-option`: this is getting out of fashion, but there are a few older software packages that reserved the dash for short options, and the plus sign for long options. Not used much today, mostly because most getopt() implementations don't support it
- `long-option`: unfortunately there are also some applications which confuse *options* with *arguments*. I believe MegaCLI is one of the offenders there (it is an offender in pretty much everything else, anyway).

Comment: `dd` is, I guess, the canonical offender of the last kind; and `tar` and `ps` have odd argument conventions, too.

Comment: This is often explained as "BSD `ps`", but in fact the BSD `ps` switched to `getopt` in 1990, and isn't the example that it is claimed to be.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511530/5132

Answer (score 6):

The `--long-opt` method is a GNUism that has been initiated around 1990.

`Multics` uses `-long` options with a single dash and the Multics project was initiated the 1960s.

`UNOS` is the first `UNIX` clone (initiated by a group of former AT&T employees in 1980) and `UNOS` introduced a generalized option parser (the first in the `UNIX` world) in April 1982. This option parser supported `-long` options with a single dash.

`AT&T` introduced `getopt()` between 1983 and 1984, but `getopt()` was not reentrant before an additional 4th global variable has been introduced in 1989 for the Bourne Shell's builtin `getopts`.

`POSIX` implements operands that look like long options with a single dash with `test` and `find`

`AT&T UNIX` introduced `-long` options using a single dash around 1983 while permitting e.g. `kill -INT <pid>`.

`tar` and `ar` did not use the term `option` in their documentation at all but rather used the term `keyletter`. Later, implementors added support for a `-` keyletter that is ignored, giving the impression that y CLI may look like other UNIX commands.

`dd` uses an own option model, but this option model is compatible with the long option model from `UNOS` that defines long options to be in the following form:

- `-long`
- `-long arg`
- `long=arg`
- `-long=arg`
- `long= arg`
- `-long= arg`

The `UNOS` option parser is superior to the GNU longopt implementation as it uses a format string that allows to auto-convert integer and boolean arguments and as it allows to implement callback functions for eny option if desired. There is no need to reorder the argument list because of the callback function interface.

The Solaris `getopt()` implementation supports long options as aliases to short options since 2004 but did not really document it even though it was usable by the `Bourne Shell` via `getopts(1)`since it was introduced.

The `Schily Bourne Shell` documents this feature and in addition introduced further `getopt()` enhancements that permit long options that are not just aliases to a short option and that permit single dash long options.

See http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html in the builtin commands section for `getopts.`

A modernized and enhanced option parser that is based on the ideas of the `UNOS` option parser is in the schily-tools in `libschily/getargs.c`

http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/

it is used in the schily tool programs that are not based on AT&T code and results in less problems with unhappy defined options names such as in `mkisofs`

Comment: [Go's standard option parsing](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) works very like UNOS's, so I guess that's where Go got its inspiration.

Comment: go does not seem to support a format string similar to what `getargs()` offers.

Comment: Nope. In go, each option is set up individually, and has an associated variable and type (so that conversion is also done automatically). And you can have one or two leading hyphens for long options.