# How to find out the version number of `dash` without resorting to package management systems?

Tags: dash

I have been using `bash` most of the time and has just started playing with other shells. I started with `dash` and tries to find out its version number but the usual method like `-v` or `$version` does not work. I can understand that `--version` is not going to work as that is GNU specific. I searched the net and found the following answers, all resorting to the package management system.

[How to tell the version number of dash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660724/how-to-tell-the-version-number-of-dash) (the user is using CentOS, so the answer depends on the Redhat Package Management system)

and

[How to find the version of the dash shell on Ubuntu bin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283134/how-to-find-the-version-of-the-dash-shell-on-ubuntu-bin) (This is from the AskUbuntu site so the answer depends on the Advanced Package Tool)

So is there a way to find out the version of `dash` without resorting to the package management system? I will be very surprised if there are no simple way because I have always believed that querying the version of a software is one of the most fundamental functions. If that is really the case, I would be happy to hear some explanation e.g. what is the philosophy behind such design. I will be happy to accept either a simple way to get the `dash` version without resorting to the package management system or a convincing explanation (historical perspective also OK) on why I cannot do it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Can the one who has downvoted the question tell me how I can possibly make the question better? I will be happy to follow up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have always believed that querying the version of a software is one of the most fundamental functions.

It isn't.  It is a good idea that we had to learn.

Many years ago, we didn't get a kernel, a package manager, and a package repository.  We got *an operating system*.  *That* had a version, and implicitly all of the operating system's component programs were associated with the operating system's version.  This was as true for BSD as it was for PC-DOS.

The AT&T world at the start of the 1980s gave us the `what` program and the idea of embedded version strings put into binaries by the source code control system.  For a while one could use that to find out the versions of things, albeit that often it was the versions of individual source files in a program rather than for the program as a whole.  (I myself put this mechanism into all of my version 1 Command-Line Utilities for DOS and for OS/2, alongside a 16-bit `WHAT` program.)

One still can today with a few OpenBSD …

```
$ what /bin/sh
/bin/sh
        PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2
$
```

… and FreeBSD binaries …

```
% what /bin/tcsh
/bin/tcsh:
     Copyright (c) 1991 The Regents of the University of California.
%
```

… but this is not the case with even most other programs on OpenBSD and FreeBSD any more, and certainly not with the Almquist shell on FreeBSD …

```
% what /bin/sh
/bin/sh:
%
```

… nor with the Debian Almquist shell.

```
% what /bin/dash
/bin/dash:
%
```

In 1988, Digital Research gave the world the idea that tools took a `/?` option to ask for option help, which Microsoft copied from DR-DOS into version 5.0 of its MS-DOS in 1991 and IBM into OS/2 in 1992.  This idea, widely touted by word of mouth, on Fidonet, and in computer magazines at the time as a very good thing, found its way into GNU coding conventions as a `--help` option, to which was added a `--version` option.  But this was not widespread for non-GNU tools in the Unix world, nor indeed widespread at the time that the Almquist shell was written in 1989; as the GNU convention did not even appear until the 1990s.

The Bourne Again shell (first published 1989) nowadays supports `--version`.  This was likewise added to the MirBSD Korn shell (the original Korn shell being first published in 1983, remember), the TENEX C shell (1983), and the Z shell (1990) which also nowadays all support `--version`.   This mechanism has not, however, been added to the Almquist shell, even by the Debian people when they made their *Debian Almquist* shell decades later.

From within the shells themselves, many shells (including several of the Korn variants, the Z shell, the Bourne Again shell, and the TENEX C shell) have a `shellname_VERSION` or `version` shell variable that can be accessed in shell script.  Again, the Almquist shell has not.

## Further reading

- Mike Miller (2014-10-06). *[consider providing a `DASH_VERSION` variable](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=764172)*.  Debian bug #764172.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257764/5132

Comment: Thank you very much. I have really learnt a lot from the historical perspectives and I really appreciate them. The earliest OS I have used is the MS-DOS which was used to launch Windows 3.x ...

Comment: If your dash is via homebrew, then: `brew info dash` gives the version number.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file` as workaround.

`file $(which dash)`:

`/usr/bin/dash: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=812a16ad1517b3d714e7b3bdb5470b2c82eb25ff, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped`

Comment: This workaround doesn't help with `>` and `<` comparisons at all... Just exact versions.