# chmod always gives "illegal option" error

Tags: bash, terminal, osx

No matter what chmod command I run, I am always getting

```
chmod: illegal option -- -
usage:  chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-a | +a | =a  [i][# [ n]]] mode|entry file ...
    chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-E | -C | -N | -i | -I] file ...
```

I am on macOS Sierra and I get the same issue on both "Terminal" as well as "iTerm2".

I have also been able to use chmod without issues on this machine in the past 2 years.

Comment: Do you have chmod aliased to something? what does `type chmod` say?

Comment: @steeldriver chmod is aliased to `chmod --preserve-root'

Comment: So this is possibly related: [Why does my ls --help not work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207136/why-does-my-ls-help-not-work) - I don't think OSX `chmod` supports long options such as `--preserve-root`

Comment: that was it! perfect. thanks. Can u pls add this as an answer so i can accept.